# sort NSMutablearray having range objects

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have add the range objects to NSMutable array i.e. [{5, 12} {0, 4} {18, 10}]. Now I want to sort this NSMutable array in increasing order. I am using the following code to get the NSMutable array objects in increasing order.

```
        NSArray *stringIndexes = [StringIndexes copy];
        stringIndexes = [stringIndexes sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
        NSLog(@"stringIndexes..:%@",stringIndexes);
```

But it is not giving the required output. If anyone know that how to sort the NSMutable array having range objects. Please help me out.

Thanks to all.

Comment: How have you added `NSRange` to a mutable array? `NSRange` isn't an object, it's a struct.

Comment: I have added the NSRange to a nsmutable array.

Comment: NSRange is not an Objective-C object... If you trying to added NSRange, show to error "Collection element of type "NSRange"(aka _NSRange) is not an Objective-C object.

Comment: 'I have added the NSRange to a nsmutable array' - __how__? add some code to your question!

Comment: Please show the code of your `compare:` method, chances are it is not unwrapping the ranges correctly.

Comment: @deanWombourne I would be surprised if it's anything other than `[NSValue valueWithRange:...]` :)

Comment: NSString *Rangstr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",NSStringFromRange(range)];
                [StringIndexes addObject:Rangstr];

Comment: You should probably change your question title to say 'How to sort an array of NSStrings'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to add ranges to an array, use

```
NSValue *value = [NSValue valueWithRange:(NSRange)range];
```

When you want to sort the array:

```
[myArray sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSValue *val1, NSValue *val2, BOOL *stop) {
  NSRange range1 = [val1 rangeValue];
  NSRange range2 = [val2 rangeValue];
  // you need to fine tune the test below - not sure what you want
  if(range1.location == range2.location) return NSOrderedSame;
  if(range1.location < range2.location) return NSOrderedAscending;
  if(range1.location > range2.location) return NSOrderedDescending;
  assert(!"Impossible");
  } ];
```